# Streaming videos from AWS to Moodle Mobile App

Tags: amazon-web-services, moodle, aws-mediatailor

I would like to know if it is possible to stream MediaTailor content on the Moodle Mobile App?

I have tested it out on our Moodle website and it works perfectly fine. However, streaming the content on the Moodle Mobile App does not work. Is there any way in which I can stream content using a MediaTailor URL?

**Update:**
I was able to emulate this issue in the browser and the following error was displayed on my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'techOrder' of undefined
    at HTMLVideoElement.<anonymous> (first.js:306)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.each (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at t (first.js:306)
    at Object.s [as setUp] (first.js:306)
    at view.php?id=41359:3335
    at Object.execCb (require.min.js:5)
    at b.check (require.min.js:5)
    at b.enable (require.min.js:5)
    at b.init (require.min.js:5)
```

This is a known issue that is currently not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to stream any DASH or HLS content or is it just the ads coming from MediaTailor that fail to stream?  If it does work with other content, there may be an issue with that the app can't handle discontinuities between main content and ads. I would recommend looking at the device logs, if there are any, to see what the player is erroring out on. In addition, I would recommend reviewing the below article from Moodle for creating mobile-friendly courses as well as the articles for debugging your app from Android Developers:

`https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Creating_mobile-friendly_courses`
`https://developer.android.com/studio/debug`
`https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb`

Comment: Hi. Sorry about the delayed response. The streaming works fine from the Moodle website and our custom Flutter app. The Moodle app does not work for some reason. I cannot even have a look at the debug logs because I have not developed the app.
However, we moved to Publit. It works fine with this service and their custom video player.